# how to create SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE user_id = id; in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to create a page that can show data where user_id = user_id logged in
here is my controller that select all data from table, i want to filter it with corresponding logged in user id

```
public function staffHome()
    {
        $posts = Post::latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('staffHome', compact('posts'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }
```

and here is my view

```
 @foreach ($posts as $post)
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{ ++$i }}</td>
        <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <form action="{{ route('posts.destroy',$post->id) }}" method="POST">

                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{{ route('posts.show',$post->id) }}">Show</a>

                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{{ route('posts.edit',$post->id) }}">Edit</a>

                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Apakah Anda yakin ingin menghapus data ini?')">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

thanks in advance

Comment: by reading the docs of laravel, where you find the where() function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should be like this

```
public function staffHome()
{
   $posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id())->latest()->paginate(5);

    return view('staffHome', compact('posts'))->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts = Post::where('user_id', $user_id)->latest()->paginate(5);
```

Please see: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-where

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

`$posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id())->latest()->paginate(5);`

Where `Auth::id()` is currently logged in user's id.

Or with relation

`Auth::user()->posts()->->latest()->paginate(5);`